# Creating a json object in Java

Tags: java, json

I am new to Java, I am trying to create the following JSON format, below is the code I am trying but it is not working. I am trying to generate a JSON format with the below code logic, can someone help me with the correct way of doing this.

The Current JSON :

```
 {
    "phoneCallsMade": [{}],
    "patientId": "1234558820-HT5",
    "campaignId": "0",
    "message": [{
        "messageCategory": "ABBB",
        "messageIdentifier": "Z1231ont",
        "messageSequenceNumber": "376",
        "messageSentTime": "2020-11-12 10:06:06.0"
    }]
}, {
    "phoneCallsMade": [{}],
    "patientId": "1234558820-HT5",
    "campaignId": "0",
    "message": [{
        "messageCategory": "TETTTr",
        "messageIdentifier": "bbbbb",
        "messageSequenceNumber": "377",
        "messageSentTime": "2020-11-12 10:06:08.0"
    }]
}, {
    "phoneCallsMade": [{}],
    "patientId": "1234558820-HT5",
    "campaignId": "0",
    "message": [{
        "messageCategory": "TEST",
        "messageIdentifier": "aaaaaaa",
        "messageSequenceNumber": "381",
        "messageSentTime": "2020-11-12 10:07:03.0"
    }]
}, {
    "phoneCallsMade": [{}],
    "patientId": "1234558820-HT5",
    "campaignId": "0",
    "message": [{
        "messageCategory": "ABC",
        "messageIdentifier": "erererer",
        "messageSequenceNumber": "382",
        "messageSentTime": "2020-11-12 10:07:05.0"
    }]
```

**Required JSON Format :**

```
{
   "report":[
      {
         "patientId":123456789012,
         "campaignId":1234567890,      
         "message":[
             {
                  "messageSequenceNumber":12345678901234567890,
                  "messageIdentifier":"aaaaaaaaaaa",
                  "messageSentTime":"2020-20-08 14:19:05",
                  "messageCategory":"bbbbb"
             }
         ],
         "phoneCallsMade":[
             {
                  "timestamp":"2020-20-08 15:19:05",
                  "outboundPhoneNumber":"1234567890",
                  "duration":"0000-00-00 0:19:05"
             }
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

**Code I tried to generate the required JSON format:**

```
data = new JSONObject();
            
messageDataJSON = new JSONObject();
callDataJSON = new JSONObject();

List<FileVO> messageData = null;            
List<FileVO> callData = null;   

for (FileVO reportVO : reportData) {                
    try {

        data.put("patientId", reportVO.getId());
        data.put("campaignId", reportVO.getEventId());
        
        bw.append(data.toString()+',');

        // Get messages for the patientId/CampaignId
        messageData = FileProcessDao.getMessageData(reportVO.getEventId(), connection,logger);
        
        for (FileVO messageVO : messageData) {
            // Prepare the array for users
            
            JSONArray arraymessage = new JSONArray();
            JSONObject message = new JSONObject();                          
            
            message.put("messageSequenceNumber",messageVO.getMessageSequenceNumber());
            message.put("messageIdentifier",messageVO.getMessageIdentifier());
            message.put("messageSentTime",messageVO.getMessageSentTime());
            message.put("messageCategory",messageVO.getMessageCategory());
            
            arraymessage.put(message);                      
            data.put("message", arraymessage);      
            bw.append(data.toString());
        }
    
        
        // Get call details for the patientId
        callData = FileProcessDao.getCallData(reportVO.getId(), connection,logger);
        
        for (FileVO callVO : callData) {
            JSONArray phoneCallsMade = new JSONArray();     
            JSONObject phones = new JSONObject();
            
            phones.put("timestamp",callVO.getEffectiveDate());
            phones.put("outboundPhoneNumber",callVO.getHcpNumber());
            phones.put("duration",callVO.getCallDuration());
            
            phoneCallsMade.put(phones);     
            data.put("phoneCallsMade", phoneCallsMade);
            bw.append(data.toString());
        }
        
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        logger.error("", e);
    }
}
JSONArray report = new JSONArray();
JSONObject finalObject = new JSONObject();

report.put(data);

finalObject.put("report", report);
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the result you present comes from the first `bw.append(data.toString())` (at the end of the loop `for (FileVO messageVO : messageData) {`.
Are there any elements in the `callData`?

I think, that for JsonSerialization it is better to use a library like [json-b](https://javaee.github.io/jsonb-spec/) or [jackson](https://mkyong.com/java/jackson-how-to-parse-json/) or other. This way you can create JSON directly from class objects without any boiler-plate code.

I think Jackson would be the easiest option. It is also the standard way the most widely used framework - Spring does it.

Comment: yes there are elements in callData but not for all ids

Answer (score 0):

For Required JSON Format, you can assemble like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        Map<String, List<Object>> outMap = new HashMap<>();
        Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap();
        map.put("patientId", 123456789012L);
        map.put("campaignId", 1234567890);

        Map<String, Object> messageMap = new HashMap();
        messageMap.put("messageSequenceNumber", "12345678901234567890");
        messageMap.put("messageIdentifier","aaaaaaaaaaa");
        messageMap.put("messageSentTime","2020-20-08 14:19:05");
        messageMap.put("messageCategory","bbbbb");
        map.put("message",Collections.singletonList(messageMap));

        Map<String, Object> phoneCallsMadeMap = new HashMap();
        phoneCallsMadeMap.put("timestamp","2020-20-08 15:19:05");
        phoneCallsMadeMap.put("outboundPhoneNumber","1234567890");
        phoneCallsMadeMap.put("duration","0000-00-00 0:19:05");
        map.put("phoneCallsMade", Collections.singletonList(phoneCallsMadeMap));

        outMap.put("report", Collections.singletonList(map));

        System.out.println(gson.toJson(outMap));

    }
```